# Django on AWS Beanstalk errors when using Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have an Django application using RDS Postgres on AWS Beanstalk.  The Beanstalk environment *does not* use the default RDS setup.  I have a separate RDS instance of Postgres running.

In my settings file I have the below for my database dictionary:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
}
```

When I visit the environment's URL I get a 500 error.  Below are the `error_logs` for one visit.

```
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.116897 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0] mod_wsgi (pid=1881): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/my_app/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.117094 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0] mod_wsgi (pid=1881): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/my_app/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.117230 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.117313 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/current/app/my_app/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.117458 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.117553 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.117668 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.117757 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.117899 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.117971 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.118183 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     app_config.import_models()
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.118266 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.118444 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.118511 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.118625 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     __import__(name)
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.118687 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.118874 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.118956 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.119098 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.119159 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.120069 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.120155 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.120229 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.120306 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.120597 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.120827 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.120943 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.121023 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.121191 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.121260 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.121347 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.121415 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.121495 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     __import__(name)
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.121550 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.121728 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0]     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
[Sun Dec 23 18:43:24.121799 2018] [:error] [pid 1881] [remote 172.31.30.131:0] ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2
```

If I comment out my Database dictionary and visit a view that does not query the Database I get a 200 and the content as expected.  If I then uncomment the Database dictionary I get a 500 no matter what view I visit.

In my `requirements.txt` I have `Django==1.11.17` and `psycopg2==2.7.5`.  I can see from the `eb-activity.log` where these are being successfully installed by PIP when the environment is created or updated.

I'm really at a loss as to what the issue could be at this point.

Comment: Can you please post the eb-activity log where they are being installed?  My initial guess would be that somehow psycopg2 was not installed properly in the vm, and I'm hoping the logs shed some light on that.

Comment: After messing with this for another day I found another clue.  After each deploy the PYTHONPATH is not being set correctly.  In my environment configuration I am using `/opt/python/current/app:$PYTHONPATH`.  If I do a deploy I have to go in and swap the location of `$PYTHONPATH` and it will work until the next deploy at which time I will have to swap them again.  I am looking into this issue but am stumped so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this ended up being a Python Path issue.  The solution surfaced in this comment from an article on setting up Django on EB:  https://realpython.com/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/#comment-2849390172